# Drupal 7 - how to allow an application to access a certain drupal url (from menu hook), either with super basic url-based auth or anonymously

Tags: authentication, drupal, drupal-7, anonymous

I'm pretty new to drupal, so bear with me if I'm not using correct terms.
I'm trying to give a stupidly basic application access to a drupal url - this application cannot do any complicated authentication.

Otherwise, this drupal system needs authentication and all other menu hooks use `'access arguments' => array('access content')`

Even before looking a solution for easy authentication method with drupal like `http://user:password@server.com/awesome/member/12345`, I've tried just giving anonymous access with the following code block in a drupal `.module` file

```
function awesome_module_menu() {
  $items['awesome/member/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Awesome member',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'aw_memberdata_fetch',
    'delivery callback' => 'aw_memberdata_deliver',
    'access arguments' => TRUE // this supposedly should allow anonymous access - from the web
  );
  return $items;
}
```

I have these two functions, one to fetch the data, one to show it:

```
function aw_memberdata_fetch(memberId)
{
    //fetch array of objects from DB
    ...
    return $items;
}
function aw_memberdata_deliver($items)
{
    switch(arg(3)) //format, comes after items
    {
      case 'json':
        drupal_json_output($items);
      break;
      default: 
        $output = makeHtml($items); //makes HTML
        drupal_deliver_html_page($output);
    }
}
```

With an authenticated browser, this works as intented. From a browser with no auth cookie I'm allowed to see the HTML, but the results are not there, it's like the `page callback` function doesn't run for anon users, but `delivery callback` does.

How do I make this work for anon users?

Comment: In the hook_menu I would add:'page arguments' => array(2),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `access arguments` with the default `user_access` function for permission verification. This will basically call `user_access(true)` which will return

- `true` for authenticated user (you are probably testing with the administrator account (uid = 1)) which bypasses the verification check. Administrator has full privileges.
- `false` for anonymous users because the string value of the first argument passed to the `user_access` `true` doesn't exist as a permission setting.

You should use either use

- a custom `YOURMODULE_access` hook which does the permission verification
- declare custom permissions for your module (`YOURMODULE_permission` hook)
- don't use permission verification by using `'access callback' => true` which gives access to anonymous and authenticated users

```
function awesome_module_menu() {
    $items['awesome/member/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Awesome member',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'page callback' => 'aw_memberdata_fetch',
        'delivery callback' => 'aw_memberdata_deliver',
        'access callback' => true,
    );

    return $items;
}
```